# jQuery - capture element and assign to variable

Tags: jquery, element

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to assign lets say the entire  tag with the specific class to a variable and then use it to replace another element.

The scenario is very simple - you click on the button in the form, button is assigned to variable (the entire button not just attribute of it or value - the html element), we replace the button with some other element (say Processing.. message or animated gif) and once ajax call is finished and was unsuccessful, we replace the 'Processing..' element back with our button.

The only way I would currently do it would be to wrap the trigger (button) with some div and use html() to get the button and replace it with the new content - then reverse it, but we're left with the wrapping div.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.clone()` - it completely clones the element including the class names and such. [jQuery Api](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea - I'm going to give it a try now and post the results.

Answer (score 2):

why not just hide them?

```
$("#button").hide();
$("#loading").show();
```

Comment: Well - as you can see you're using ids - and that's not great - what if you have several forms on the page - here's where the problems start popping up. I'll try Phil's suggestion with the clone(). Thanks for suggestion anyway.

Comment: it was an example... You can use any selector you need. You also need a selector to find an element to .clone()

Comment: @user398341 - If you have multiple places of this in your page, then you should just give each it's own ID or you can give them all the same class and use parent scoping with the selector to identify which you're targeting like $(".header .loadButton").hide();  This is basic CSS selectors.

Comment: Absolutely - it's all fine, but I prefer the .clone() option.